# Inline Maven Checkstyle Plugin: Are there defaults and how do you override them?

Tags: maven, checkstyle

I have a Java project that is based on 3 projects. We would like the to manage everything with an external parent pom that we can have various related projects extend from. Therefore, there is a parent module in and of itself and all of the child modules just point to the parent artifact.

I have configured checkstyle to run in the parent so that we can eventually enforce code style on any project in the family, the definition in the parent is as such:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${checkstyle.plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>validate</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <logViolationsToConsole>true</logViolationsToConsole>
                        <!-- checkstyle configuration starts here -->
                            <checkstyleRules>
                                <module name="Checker">
                                <!-- rule for no tab characters in a file -->
                                    <module name="FileTabCharacter" />
                                </module>
                            </checkstyleRules>
                            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                            <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
                            <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>
                            <linkXRef>false</linkXRef>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>checkstyle</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

As you can see there is only one rule currently configured for the time being. However, my builds are failing because other rules are being applied, as evidenced by the contents of the checkstyle-checker.xml that is produced in the target directories. Are there defaults that are applied to the checkstyle plugin? If so, how do I override them?